Show total number of pages in Oracle Apex Interactive grid pdf export
I have a interactive grid report in Oracle apex. I have a requirement where I need to show the total number of pages in the header of the exported PDF of this report. Does anyone know how could I get the total number of pages?
I have tried getting the number of pages via number of rows and dividing it by pagination size(20 for me), but it doesn't give correct number of pages as I think the number of rows per page changes when exporting the report.
